# How to check if a user(already registered with log in form) exists in the database?

Tags: php, database

I've been trying to create a login page where users who sign up are written in a database. I want to check, when a user tries to log in, the code should find if the user is registered before(if exists in the table in the database). And if exists he should sign in and to be redirected to another page(in this case kontakt.php). Here's what I've done till now, but it shows me error:
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookShop\login.php on line 14
Is something wrong with the query?

```
<?php
session_start();
require "C:/xampp/htdocs/BookShop/DButils.php";

//opening a DB connection
$connection = @ mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

//selecting DB
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kupuvac WHERE username = '$username'             AND password = '$password'"));

if($query == 1)
 {              

   header("Location:kontakt.php");

  }
else if ($query == 0 )
   {

    echo "Please try again";
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: There's probably an error in your SQL query. You can see it by ```echo```ing ```mysql_error()``` right after the execution.

Comment: Try this: $query = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT..")) or die(mysql_error());  That way you can see what the error is and post it here

Comment: on different topic, using full path in require like in: "C:/xampp/htdocs/BookShop/DButils.php"; is bad idea for portability of the app, you should use relative paths

Comment: try with `if($query >= 1)` and see what happen.... also `echo $query` before if statement and let me know it shows...

Comment: When I added mysql_error() nothing happens, just displaying a blank page.

Comment: the warning line is the $query line

Comment: could you please display here what you get for `echo $query`

Comment: @FahimParkar it shows me the else message "Please try again" when I enter incorrect username or password, but when i enter a username or password that is already in the database it shows we "Object not found" page.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP... Is `header("Location:kontakt.php");` this correct?? Try to print `echo "I m here"` instead of `header("Location:kontakt.php");` and see what comes.. if it comes `I m here` means there is problem in your statement `header("Location:kontakt.php");`... Good Luck

Comment: the location was the mistake, it was my mistake :) tnx

Comment: trigger_error(mysql_error().$query) to see where you made the error.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource if the query is successful, but it returns `FALSE` if there is an error.

From PHP's website:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

Answer (score 0):

You should ***always*** check your results for validity.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```